# Pandas dataframe rows to dict of lists, using first value of each row as key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
```

---

## SETUP

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                   'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                   'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                   'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

ie:

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    | A   | B   | C   | D   |
|----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
|  0 | A0  | B0  | C0  | D0  |
|  1 | A1  | B1  | C1  | D1  |
|  2 | A2  | B2  | C2  | D2  |
|  3 | A3  | B3  | C3  | D3  |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

<sub>(using [`print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528533/pretty-printing-a-pandas-dataframe/31885295#31885295), [related Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63547508/how-to-read-in-pretty-printed-dataframe-into-a-pandas-dataframe))</sub>

---

## PROBLEM

I would like to convert the above dataframe into this dict:

```
{'A0': ['A0', 'B0', 'C0', 'D0'],
 'A1': ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'],
 'A2': ['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'],
 'A3': ['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3']}
```

The first element from each row are the keys, the rows of the dataframes are the values for the dict as lists.

---

## SOLUTIONS

**A**
Using `.iterrows()`, which [seems bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/8565438):

```
`{row[1][0]: list(row[1]) for row in df.iterrows() for alias in row[1]}`
```

**B**
Using `.groupby()` [(and this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132654/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-dict-with-unique-column-values-as-keys/54132728#54132728):

```
gbdict=df.groupby('A').apply(lambda row: row.to_dict(orient='row')).to_dict()
{key: list(gbdict[key][0].values()) for key in gbdict.keys()}
```

They both produce the required output.

---

## QUESTION

**Is there a more efficient way to achieve the above goal?**

If there could be a way *[without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/are-for-loops-in-pandas-really-bad-when-should-i-care) the for loop*, ie the [dict comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension), that'd be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this , I think this will faster than `agg` ~

```
yourdict = dict(zip(df.A,df.values.tolist()))
Out[123]: 
{'A0': ['A0', 'B0', 'C0', 'D0'],
 'A1': ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'],
 'A2': ['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'],
 'A3': ['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3']}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `set_index` then `agg` using `list` on `axis=1` and use `Series.to_dict`:

```
dct = df.set_index(df['A']).agg(list, axis=1).to_dict()
```

Result:

```
{'A0': ['A0', 'B0', 'C0', 'D0'],
 'A1': ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'],
 'A2': ['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'],
 'A3': ['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3']}
```